# why is my apache / php is not running under the right user

Tags: php, windows, apache, terminal

i used 
`echo exec("whoami");`
and i got

> authority\system

and in my httpd.conf 
it says

> User daemon
>   Group daemon

why is it not running on the right user ?
also i checked and created the user and restarted apache but still it's running under system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`User` and `Group` are ignored on non-POSIX systems. You need to modify the relevant service entry instead under Windows.